# How to find a value of a specified object property in a array using mongoose find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema

```
{
_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
totalCreatedForms: [
{formName: "formone", formIndex: 0},
{formName: "formtwo", formIndex: 1},
{formName: "formthree", formIndex: 2}
]
}
```

I used mongoose query to find the form I need as follows:

```
db.collection.find({"totalCreatedForms.formName":"formtwo"}, data=>{res.send(data)})
```

Is there a way, I can get the value of formIndex of the specified form. Here I am getting the whole data of the "_id", I have to filter again it in the front-end. But, I am wondering if there is a query to get the values of the specified form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `$` operator in this way:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "totalCreatedForms.formName": "formtwo"
},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "totalCreatedForms.formIndex.$": 1
})
```

Find query has two objects.

The first to match the element you are looking for.

The second one is to indicate which fields returns. So, `_id` field will not be returned and, from array, only the index where the positional operator is placed, will be returned.

Ouput example is like this:

```json
[
  {
    "totalCreatedForms": [
      {
        "formIndex": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that mongo is a data base who store documents and return documents, so this is the easiest way (without aggregation) to get only the value you want instead of the entire array.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OhnpNFhAeia)